# Android app that will continue playing video audio after turning off screen

Tags: android, video

Situation: You've downloaded videos as mp4s and put them on your phone. You want to watch them on your phone. Sometimes, you want to turn the screen off while keeping the phone on, put the phone in your pocket, and keep listening to the audio in the video.

I have a samsung galaxy s6. The default video app will stop the audio if I turn off the screen. **What android app would be my best bet to solve this?**

Budget: Less than 20$ for the app

Why converting videos to mp3 is not the solution to this: first, you cannot watch the video if you've converted it to an mp3. Second, I don't have a batch converter for mp4 to mp3

Why a simple google search for this didn't work: 
Searching "Android app that will continue playing video audio after turning off screen" will give you links referring to youtube. My question is not about youtube- it is about viewing videos you have downloaded on your phone. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+app+that+will+continue+playing+video+audio+after+turning+off+screen&oq=Android+app+that+will+continue+playing+video+audio+after+turning+off+screen&aqs=chrome..69i57.168j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Mxplayer support this feature but you have to unable it by going into settings.

It supports many other things like

> a) HARDWARE ACCELERATION - Hardware acceleration can be applied to
>   more videos with the help of new HW+ decoder.
>
> b) MULTI-CORE DECODING - MX Player is the first Android video player
>   which supports multi-core decoding. Test result proved that dual-core
>   device's performance is up to 70% better than single-core devices.
>
> c) PINCH TO ZOOM, ZOOM AND PAN - Easily zoom in and out by pinching
>   and swiping across the screen. Zoom and Pan is also available by
>   option.
>
> d) SUBTITLE GESTURES - Scroll forward/backward to move to
>   next/previous text, Up/down to move text up and down, Zoom in/out to
>   change text size.
>
> e) KIDS LOCK - Keep your kids entertained without having to worry that
>   they can make calls or touch other apps. (plugin required)

Very powerful and they release updates very often.

There are two versions

Regular: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en

Pro: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro&hl=en

Comment: I downloaded the app and, under the Screen settings, I cannot find the setting to enable audio to keep going after I've turned off the screen. Where do I go to enable this?

Comment: Go into player settings you will find background play enable it.